# [__NSArrayM addObjectsFromArray:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x283e8c990 - Apprtc

Tags: objective-c

[image: application crashing here]

[image: This is log]

i'm trying to implement video call via apprtc. apprtc working fine for all other demo i've build but when i'm implementing it in my main project it is showing this error. don't know what to do

Comment: Can you post your code snippet here?

Answer (score -1):

This error just means the array you are adding data to or the array you are adding data from is not allocated or nil. First check both their values and make sure there is ideal data situation for the line to execute

Comment: checked it everything is seems all right.. same code working fine in all other projects..!!

Comment: `nil` is ok in Objective-C. Not allocated is `nil` with ARC.